# Internet connection dropping intermittently on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, internet, gigabyte

I have the Gigabyte Z490M-ITX board with its built in Wi-Fi adapter. When I boot Windows, the connection is flawless. However when I am using Linux, the connection drops occasionally for a few seconds to around a minute. This problem is not unique to Ubuntu either, previously I was using Manjaro and the same thing was happening.

Ubuntu 20.04 focal (x86-64)

[Network graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwyi2.png)

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: @waltinatorI im still a bit new to using the panel, I was got the sudo journalctl part but what does -b, and 0 mean in the panel?

Comment: Read `man journalctl`. It's explained there.